# Avoiding recomputation on changing state in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component `Parent` whose state is a list of values, and the user can add to that list of values, which calls `this.setState((state,props) => {return {items : state.items.concat(newItem);})`.

I have another component `Child` which takes `state.items` via props and wants to display each item. Preparing the items for display involves some relatively expensive function `f` being applied to each item. How can I avoid applying `f` more than necessary?

- I can move applying `f` into `Parent`, and maintain `itemsF`, and then on each new item perform `items: state.items.concat(f(newItem))`. This approach ensures `f` is applied the minimum number of times, but breaks the encapsulation of `Child` (and in reality there are several children with different functions, which is even worse).
- I can apply `f` inside `Child`, but then it gets reapplied to all old values.

What is the right way to get both sensible abstraction and performance? Is there anything more explicitly stream-like than appending to a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make Child [pure](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) so that it only re-renders when it's props change.

2) Make sure you've assigned unique refs to all Child components in the list.

3) Move "f" into Child's render function.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any more general technique if I want to also pass the transformed itemsF to a child of Child?

Comment: Not sure if I got your question right. I usually make _everything_ pure. As long as nothing changes in Child's props then neither any of it's children will re-render. I also don't shy from passing complex data as props. What I also find is that things like your function "f" are better called right after the action causing it's need to be called happens. Like a user clicking a "add new row" button. That's why I usually use Redux. A Store contains all the data I need to render a complete screen. No processing in components, only in actions when they are called.

Comment: Thanks, looks like "use Redux" might really be the answer I was looking for!